# Help with some driving related phrases?

Tags: phrase-request

I would like to know the most natural/everyday/colloquial way for a native speaker (preferably, N.Am dialect) to put below things into words: (basically the first phrase that comes to your mind, if you want to say it in an everyday, casual style, please.)

**Context 1. Staying in a parking garage:**

i.e., would it be correct to say:

*how long is your car going to remain parked in the garage?* **Or...?**

**Context 2. Moving a vehicle out of a garage:**

i.e., would it be correct to say: 
*when are you going to get off the garage? Pull out of the garage? Move your car out of the garage? Exit from the garage?* **Or...?**

**Context 3. Moving a vehicle into the garage:**

i.e., would it be correct to say:

*when did you get in the garage? When did you pull into garage? When did you enter the garage?* **Or...?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How long is your car going to remain parked in the garage?

This sentence is correct, if a bit wordy. A more colloquial way of saying this might be "How long will you be parked in the garage?".

---

> When are you going to get off the garage? Pull out of the garage? Move your car out of the garage? Exit from the garage?
>
> When did you get in the garage? When did you pull into garage? When did you enter the garage? Or...?

"Get off the garage" is incorrect, as one does not go "on" a garage. A more correct phrasing might be "get out of…" or "go out of…". The rest of these sentences are correct.

A more concise approach to the third group, however, might simply be "When did you park?".